# How to set width of html5 canvas shadowBlur?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

The context of an html5 canvas has the following attributes related to setting the shadow:

```
shadowOffsetX = float
shadowOffsetY = float
shadowBlur = float
shadowColor = color
```

None of which set the width of the shadow.
Is setting the width at all possible with canvas?

shadowBlur does seem to increase the width, but the blur becomes more opaque.

Comment: Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a way to control the intensity of the shadow, except for drawing the object multiple times. This, however, can lead to undesired results when the object itself is alpha-transparent.

Answer (score 2):

A higher value for shadowBlur **does** increase the the width of the shadow, but it unfortunately also reduces the intensity, so that a very high value creates a blur which is barely visible.

The only way to increase the intensity of the shadow is to draw the object multiple times. This, however, can lead to undesired results when the object itself is alpha-transparent and can also be a performance hook, because the already pretty expensive blur effect has to be recalculated every single pass. The performance cost can be reduced a bit by drawing the object with the blur effect to a separate, invisible canvas, and then drawing this canvas to the real canvas multiple times. Unfortunately that's still a dirty hack.

When you want to create really fancy graphic effects, you should consider using WebGL. The learning curve is pretty steep, but when you get the hang of it, you have the full power of the OpenGL Shading Language at your disposal (ok, not the *full* power - only version 1.00 - but that's already enough for a lot of nice graphic effects calculated directly on the users GPU).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Draw your object to the the canvas,
Increase the line width,
Redraw the object to a different canvas underneath,
Set a CSS3 blur effect on the canvas underneath.

Worked for me when I was drawing with paths.